# LINQ to Objects - Assign list to property

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I am trying to write a LINQ to Objects/XML query that will create objects. I 
have a class which has a property `IList` of `SomeModelClass`. `SomeModelClass` also has several `IList`'s which need to be populated from the XML.

This is the first time I've attempted to query multiple levels of nested XML and I am unsure how to proceed.

Currently the code does not compile because `select new` does not seem to be able to be nested. How can I actually query the nested XML to create an object that has a list of objects which also has a list of strings?

I have shown the code that I have attempted to far.

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set }
    public IList<SomeModelClass> ModelList { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my model class:

```
public class SomeModelClass
{
    public IList<string> MyList1 { get; set; }
}
```

The XML looks like this:

```
  <someXml>
    <section name="test">
      <myModelClassXml>
        <someValue value="string1" />
        <someValue value="string2" />
        <someValue value="string3" />
      </myModelClassXml>
    </section>

    <section name="test2">
      <myModelClassXml>
        <someValue value="string1" />
      </myModelClassXml>
    </section>
  </someXml>
```

And the code I have so far:

```
    var query = (from r in xdoc.Descendants("someXml").Descendants("section")
                 select new MyClass()
                 {
                     Name = r.Attribute("name").Value,

                     //Make list of SomeModelClass AND ALSO populate SomeModelClass's lists
                     select new SomeModelClass
                     {
                        MyList1 = What needs to be here?
                     }

                 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the correct result:-

```
List<MyClass> result = xdoc.Root.Descendants("section")
            .Select(x => new MyClass
               {
                   Name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                   ModelList = x.Elements("myModelClassXml")
                                .Select(y => new SomeModelClass 
                    {
                        MyList1 = y.Elements("someValue")
                                   .Select(z => (string)z.Attribute("value")).ToList()
                                                               }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

First find all the descendants of `section` then project it to `MyClass`. Now since `myModelClassXml` is direct child to `section`, we can use `Elements` to further fetch `someValue` element and its value attribute.